# using secret strings inside pwsh command

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I'm trying to run some commands using `pwsh` command as below:

```
$securePassword = "sdfd-334-sdfd-23fd" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force;
$ApplicationId ="sdfd-wef-dfdf-23dsd";
$Tenant = "sdfjkd-dfdsf-32r3-dfd";

pwsh -c Connect-DataGatewayServiceAccount -ApplicationId $ApplicationId -ClientSecret $securePassword -Tenant $Tenant
```

However, I get this error when I run the above script in powershell

```
PS C:\Windows\System32> powershell .\datagw.ps1
Connecting to DataGateway
Connect-DataGatewayServiceAccount: Cannot bind parameter 'ClientSecret'. 
Cannot convert the "System.Security.SecureString" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Security.SecureString".
```

For some reason the params passed to -c option are treated as System.String instead of System.Security.SecureString.
How can I pass securePassword as value of type System.Security.SecureString?

Comment: `pwsh` is an external executable (just a different version of PowerShell), so like any command-line tool, it treats inputs as strings.  Why are you calling `pwsh` when you are already in a PowerShell session?  Can't you call `Connect-DataGatewayServiceAccount`?

Comment: I'm running this as a user-data script while spinning up AWS ec2 windows server 2019. The image comes with powershell 5.1 which I can't change. DataGateway module commands only works with powershell 7 and above. So the only way I could think of running the commands as part of user-data is to install PS7 and run pwsh from within default powershell5 which aws user-data gets run in.

Comment: Is there any way you could put the connection code in a second script and have the single command `pwsh -file .\MyScript.ps1` in the original script?  That way the SecureString will be constructed inside the `pwsh` session and passed correctly to `Connect-DataGatewayServiceAccount`.

Comment: That's the way I'm running right now but that would require the automation (terraform) to pull the script file from somewhere (eg s3) and execute which is not the best approach as the script contain sensitive information. And running the commands from file is complicating the automation unnecessarily which I want to avoid if possible. Running pwsh commands from a file is straight forward but getting that file on to the server as part of bootstrapping is getting tricky!